# How to get HTML div to overlay the text in its parent div

Tags: html, css-position, z-index

I have a movable div as follows:

```
<div id=overlay style="display: none; z-index: 99; position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px;"><img src="someimage.gif"></div>
```

A javascript event listener function includes the following:

```
var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
rdiv.appendChild(overlay);
overlay.style.display = '';
```

rdiv is a div that just contains text, with no styling except width.

What I was hoping was -- the overlay image would pop up in the top left corner of rdiv, overlaying the text.  What actually happens is, the overlay image appears below the text, exactly as you would expect for a block element inserted after the text.  Giving rdiv a positioning of absolute or relative doesn't help.

Can it be done to have the overlay div appear on top of the text in the upper left corner?  Actually never mind -- just figured out that if rdiv is positioned relative and overlay is absolute it works.  Question could be deleted.

Comment: it can certainly be done. could you please provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: I just hadn't tried all combinations of positioning the parent div and child div.  If parent is relative and child is absolute it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you're appending a child to `rdiv`, then setting CSS rules on `rdiv` won't do much.  Its children will be laid out according to their own CSS rules.  If you want `overlay` to be in the top-left corner of its parent container, then you need to change the CSS for `overlay`, not `rdiv`:

```
var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
rdiv.appendChild(overlay);
overlay.style["z-index"] = 10;
overlay.style["position"] = "absolute";
overlay.style["top"] = 0;
```

(...or something similar).  You were on the right track with `overlay.style.display = '';` but I don't think you want to set the display property here.

Comment: overlay got all its styling in its original HTML code, including display=none because it's invisible until called for.  Setting display to empty string in javascript is just to make it appear.